# spring data elasticsearch: settings and mapping config with annotations not working

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using embedded elasticsearch with spring boot and I was trying to use annotations for configuring settings and mappings. I followed this [Tutorial](https://qbox.io/blog/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams) which explains how to implement searching over multiple fields. Anyway, I have defined the settings.json and the mappings.json in my document entity as described [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/entities/DynamicSettingAndMappingEntity.java) but it seems as if it is not reading the files because curl*ing* the mappings does not return the corresponding configuration as defined in the files.

Indexing is been executed by a spring batch process. It reads data from the database and writes it to elasticsearch. This works perfectly.

I get no results (should return 7 items) when I make a POST request to http://localhost:9200/profile/_search:

```
{
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
       "match": {
       "_all": {
           "query": "user male",
           "operator": "and"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

If I change the query to "user5" it returns the user with this nickname.

I will appreciate if somebody can give me a hint. What is wrong with the configuration?

**The Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages ="com.company.searchengine.repository")
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {
    @Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
    private String esClusterName;

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws IOException {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(nodeBuilder().local(true).clusterName
            (esClusterName).node()
            .client());
    }
}
```

**The document**

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "uuid")
@ToString(exclude = "uuid")
@NoArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@JsonCreator}))
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(indexName = "profiles", type = "profile", createIndex = false)
@Setting(settingPath = "/settings/settings.json")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/mappings/mappings.json")
public class IndexedProfile {
    @Id
    @NonNull
    private String uuid;
    @NonNull
    //@Field(index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, type = FieldType.String)
    private String nickname;
    @NonNull
    //@Field(index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, type = FieldType.String)
    private String gender;
    //@Field(index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, type = FieldType.String)
    private String about;
    private GeoPoint location;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.year_month_day)
    private Date birthdate;
}
```

**The batch job**

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends IndexedProfile> items) throws Exception {
    List<IndexQuery> indexQueries = items.stream()
            .map(item -> new IndexQueryBuilder().withObject(item).withId(String.valueOf(item.getUuid())))
            .map(builder -> builder.withType(DOCUMENT_TYPE))
            .map(builder -> builder.withIndexName(INDEX_NAME + runId))
            .map(IndexQueryBuilder::build)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    this.elasticsearchTemplate.bulkIndex(indexQueries);
}
```

**The settings**

```
{
  "settings": {
       "analysis": {
           "filter": {
               "nGram_filter": {
                  "type": "nGram",
                   "min_gram": 2,
                   "max_gram": 20,
                   "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit",
                        "punctuation",
                        "symbol"
                    ]
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
             "nGram_analyzer": {
                 "type": "custom",
                 "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                 "filter": [
                      "lowercase",
                      "asciifolding",
                      "nGram_filter"
                 ]
        },
        "whitespace_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
             ]
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Mappings**

```
{
  "mappings": {
      "profile": {
          "_all": {
               "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
           },
           "nickname": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           ....
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

According to `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchPersistentEntity`, with setting `createIndex=false` will cause the framework NOT to create index and mappings! So you should remove that setting or set it to true.

Answer (score 2):

The settings and the mappings JSON structures are not correct, try to adapt them using these reference examples:

Mappings: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/tree/master/src/test/resources/mappings

Settings: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/tree/master/src/test/resources/settings

Answer (score 1):

```
studentdoc_setting_index_mapping_type_overlayadjacency.json
{
        "index": {
            "mapping": {
                "total_fields": {
                    "limit": "100000"
                }
            }   
    }
}

@Setting(settingPath = "studentdoc_setting_index_mapping_type_overlayadjacency.json")
public class StudentDoc {
}
```